# Creating a SQL table variable in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sqlparameter

I want to create SQL variable table in stored procedure which include this;

```
Select a,b,c,d from **@tablename** where a=1 and c=0
```

How can do this with sp when creating sp?

Comment: Refer this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18972/Temporary-Tables-vs-Table-Variables-and-Their-Effe

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL to include the table name as a parameter in a SQL query.

Comment: This is a sign of bad database design.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? "*SQL*" is a query language, not a specific DBMS product.

Answer (score 8):

You can declare table variable in SP as:

```
DECLARE @tablename TABLE(
    a INT,
    b INT,
    c INT,
    d INT);

SELECT * FROM @tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this answer helps you**

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE PrededureName
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE
(
    a INT, 
    b INT,
    c INT,
    d INT
)
INSERT INTO @tempTable (a, b, c, d)
SELECT a, b, c, d FROM @tablename WHERE a=1 and c=0
END
GO;
```